# Control dependency by parameter attribute

Tags: vb.net, castle-windsor

Is it possible to control which dependency is created by adding a attribute to the parameter?

Example:

```
Public Sub New(textService As ITextService, <RequireWebService> addressService As IAddressService)
    m_TextService = textService
    m_AddressService = addressService
End Sub
```

ITextService should be resolved with default logic. But the IAddressService should get a different implementation, depending on whether this "RequireWebService" attribute is present.

Comment: The simplest way to manage this would be to: use a separate interface to represent the semantic difference between e.g. IAddressService and IAddressWebService; explicitly identify the desired component at registration time or implement an `IHandlerSelector`. Making the components themselves aware of a specific DI framework is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own `IHandlerSelector`.  This interface is used by Windsor to allow you to control which service is selected when Windsor tries to resolve a component.  Here's some pseudo code of what you could do (sorry for the C# -- I don't have any VB.NET code sample lying around):

```
public class AddressServiceSelector : IHandlerSelector
{
    public bool HasOpinionAbout(string key, Type service)
    {
        // tell Windsor you'd like to "help" it resolve the IAddressService
        return service == typeof(IAddressService);
    }

    public IHandler SelectHandler(string key, Type service, IHandler[] handlers)
    {
        // "webServiceAvailable" is some flag that is globally available
        // to your application which indicates the flag for how the IAddressService
        // is resolved.
        if (webServiceAvailable)
        {
            return handlers.Where(
                h => h.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof (WebAddressService))
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return handlers.Where(
            h => h.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(FileAddressService))
            .FirstOrDefault();      
    }
}
```

Configure Windsor to use this handler by using:

```
container.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(new AddressServiceSelector());
```

In this example, I'm assuming you have two implementations of `IAddressService` registered in Windsor (`WebAddressService` and `FileAddressService`).  You'll also need some "flag" available to the handler for the selection process.  If this flag is true when Windsor tries to resolve an `IAddressService`, you'll get the `WebAddressService`.  Otherwise, you get the `FileAddressService`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

I've build a little working test using ISubDependencyResolver.

But as @Phil mentioned this is a bad idea. So I'll go another way.